# Why the distinguishability changes the probability?

Tags: probability

Place $n$ **distinct** particles in $N$ **ordered** buckets where $N≥n$. The total number of possible placements is $N^n$. Choose $n$ particular buckets, then the probability of each of the $n$ bucket containing exactly one particle is $\frac{n!}{N^n}$.

Now suppose the particles are **indistinguishable**, then the number of possible placements is $C_{n+N-1}^n$ (denotes $n+N-1$ chooses $n$). Given the chosen $n$ buckets, the probability of each of the $n$ buckets containing exactly one particle is $\frac{1}{C_{n+N-1}^n }$.

Suppose $N=10, n=5$, then the first probability is $5! / 10^5 = 0.0012$, and the second probability is $1/C_{14}^5 \approx 0.0005$.

This is very counter-intuitive. The only difference between the two cases is if the particles are distinguishable. Anyone can help explain why the distinguishability changes the probability?

Comment: Are the $N$ buckets distinct?

Comment: @Nicholas Sorry. My mistake. The buckets should be distinct.

Comment: the $C_{n+N-1}^n$ ways are not equally probable

Comment: @WW1 Thanks for the reply. Can you help explain why?

Comment: The probabilities are still a little off. First part should be $\frac{\binom{N}{n}n!}{N^n}$. Second one should be $\frac{\binom{N}{n}}{\binom{n+N-1}{n}}$.

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks! The $n$ buckets are actually fixed. I rephrased my question a little bit. The probabilities in your comment are for "existence of $n$ buckets each of which has one particle". Anyway it does not matter. The probabilities are still different.

Comment: Ahh I see, you are referring to a conditional probability. Either way, the distinguishability of the objects affects the number of ways in which the event occurs. Thus, it also affects the probability of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you consider the particles as distinguishable you are specifying the state as an n-tuple whose $k^{th}$ element is the box number of the $k^{th}$ ball.

There are $N^n$ of these micro-states and they are all equally probable.

When you think of the particles as indistinguishable you are specifying the the state as an N-tuple whose elements sum to n. 
 The $p^{th}$ element is the number of of balls in the $p^{th}$ box. 
  You are then creating macro-states, whose probability will be proportional to the number of micro-states corresponding to that macro-state.

e.g.

case 1: there are $n!$ micro-states corresponding to the macro-state in which the first $n$ boxes contain 1 ball

case 2: there is only  1 micro-state corresponding to the macro-state in which all $n$ balls are contained in the first box.

both cases are described by a single macro-state 
but case 1 is more probable by a factor of $n!$

if $N=5$ and $n=2$ 

 the macro-state for case 1 is $(1,1,0,0,0)$ corresponding to the micro-states $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$

 the macro-state for case 2 is $(2,0,0,0,0)$ corresponding to the micro-state $(1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

Let us deal with a simple case, three particles and three buckets.

Consider two observers who are watching, one on a colour monitor, and the other on a carefully-contrasted black-and-white monitor, the same balls fall randomly into buckets and recording the results.   The colour monitor can distinguish the red, blue, and green balls, while the black-and-white cannot, and yet they are the same balls.   What is the probability that the balls fall into different buckets?

Now the first observer can table a total of $3^3$ possible outcomes, of these $3!$ the particles in different buckets.

The other observer can only view $^5C_3$ distinct outcomes, of which only one distinct way places one particle in each bucket.

Why will the probability both measure be closer to $3!/3^3$ rather than $1/{^5C_3}$ ?   Well, whether or not the particles can be distinguished *by an observer*, they still individual entities.   So the applicable model is: "each individual particle has an unbiased choice of one of three individual locations".

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}*|*|* & r|b|g & r|g|b & b|r|g & b|g|r & g|r|b & g|b|r 
\\ **||* & rb||g & rg||b & bg||r \\ **|*| & rb|g| & rg|b| & bg|r| \\ |**|* & |rb|g & |rg|b & |bg|r \\ |*|** & |r|bg & |b|rg & |g|rb \\ *|**| & r|bg| & b|rg| & g|rb| \\ *||** & r||bg & b||rg & g||rb
\\ *** || & rbg||
\\ |***| & |rbg|
\\ ||*** & ||rbg 
\end{array}$$

---

**tl;dr** The distinct arrangements of indistinct particles are not each equally probable states.